# Rails 4 - public_send(key, value) raises NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activesupport-concern

I have a Role class defined as :

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Filterable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

The Filterable model concern is :

```
        module Filterable
          extend ActiveSupport::Concern

          module ClassMethods
            def filter(filtering_params)
              results = self.where(nil) # create an anonymous scope
              filtering_params.each do |key, value|
                results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
              end
              results
            end
          end
        end
```

The results = self.where(nil) line , returns all roles

```
  Role Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles"
  #<Role:0x007fd22d235080>
  #<Role:0x007fd22d234ea0>
  #<Role:0x007fd22d234cc0>
```

but the results.public_send(key, value) line raises an error :

```
results.public_send(key, value)
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `company' for #       <Role::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd232499da8>
```

If I check :

```
byebug) results.first
#<Role:0x007fd22d235080> 

(byebug) results.first.inspect
#<Role id: 1, company: "internal", group: "accounting", function: 
"employee", activities: {}, created_at: "2015-09-16 06:54:19",
updated_at: "2015-09-16 06:54:19">

(byebug) results.first.company
# nothing returned !
(byebug) results.first[:company]
internal

The Role class doesn't need any attribute accessor as it's an ActiveRecord class...  the company, group, function should ahem getter/setter defined .. where am I wrong ?
```

thanks for feedback

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Goal : to get rid of scope and class method for querying and filtering models.. and it's working perfectly now

btw I don't no how to set the duplicate question I can see now at the top go the post ... that's why I answered at the bottom .. sorry for not doing it well...